# How do you use the Twitter Rest API

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

From my website, I would like any user to be able to tweet a specific url with an image to their Twitter accounts.

I have tried using the Button Widget but it seems I cannot embed media. To do that I need to use the Twitter REST API.

**Question**:
1) How do I set my webpage to use the Twitter REST API?
2) What Script do I import?
3) How do I ensure that we check first if the user is logged?
4) How do I ensure that the popup does not get blocked by the browser?

I cannot find anything that helps me on this basic steps online so I hope somebody here can help me start this project.

Many thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to most of your questions is to use a Twitter OAuth library and read up on the docs on Twitter's development site.

A library I have used is [TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth); this will take care of the authentication for you, and give you an easy way to make authenticated API calls.

Then, you will need to look at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update and/or https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media.

Comment: Does that work from a Javascript code-only point of view? 
I'm using MS-MVC but I didn't want to have to go back to the server, in fact I was hoping to handle all within a single JS function.

Is that the case?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. While you may be able to send the correct auth values via javascript, it would involve exposing your secret OAuth tokens, which, if discovered, would mean people could make API calls on behalf of your app, so you absolutely should not do it. The changes in API v1.1 to require OAuth authentication for every call essentially killed any sort of javascript implementation of anything to do with Twitter, unless it's one of their own widgets for feeds etc.

Comment: So just for me to understand ...I need an APP in order to simply post a url and image to the currently logged user. Is that so?

Comment: And also, I need to write some backend code in order to post an image and a url to the Twitter account of the logged user. IF the code runs on the backend, where would the user login on his twitter account?

This is what kind of confuses me so far :--)

Comment: Yep. They'll need to authorize their account with the app to get the access tokens required for the API call to work. The 'app' is basically just registering your integration with Twitter to get the OAuth tokens, and gives the user something to authorize.

Comment: that occurs on via Javascript on the html page and then..I'll pass his token to the backend where my code will send the tweet? Is that the way ?

Comment: That library should take care of it for you; you basically send the user to a URL which calls some code in the library, this redirects them to Twitter, they authorize the app, and get sent back to your page, which will also post some data back (access tokens) and you can then store these where you wish.

Comment: Last question ...when you say that I basically send the user to a URL, is that my URL, a Twitter URL and from where do I send the user (back-end or javascript or <a link>). That's where I'm confused. I accomplish the same on Facebook from ONE Javascript function and I guess that's what confuses me, that I kind of was hoping to have the same for Twitter. Let me know and thanks for your help on this.

Comment: That https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update ...u use it from the back-end or from a Javascript call ??

Comment: Everything needs to be backend.